# dropdown SelectedIndexChanged event is not triggering if index is changed in page_load event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down & a label, drop down is binded with a dictionary. When user changes the selected value of drop down I want to update the label. Following code works well but i want to set the initial value of label, I set the value of selected index in page_load, however event does not trigger. How to fix it? is there any page event which can help me solve the issue. I know i can fix it using javascript but I do not want to use JS.

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
                Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!this.IsPostBack)
                {
                    myDictionary.Add("1", "Test Address 1");
                    myDictionary.Add("2", "Test Address 2");
                    myDictionary.Add("3", "Test Address 3");
                    myDictionary.Add("4", "Test Address 4");
                    myDictionary.Add("5", "Test Address 5");

                    drpTest.DataSource = myDictionary;
                    drpTest.DataTextField = "Key";
                    drpTest.DataValueField = "Value";
                    drpTest.DataBind();

                    // I want to set the index & update the label lblAddress
                    drpTest.SelectedIndex = 2;


                }
            }

            protected void drpTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                lblAddress.Text = drpTest.SelectedItem.Value;
            }
```

Comment: Set dropdown's AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: Autopostback is already set to 'true'. it works well when i change the selected value from browser. However I want to set the initial value of label.

Comment: by initial value of label, do you mean the Very first time when page loads ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should call this function at page load

```
drpTest_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null)
```

and it doesn't trigger as normal because you didn't change the dropdown selected value after initializing the page and ready to be used for client

Comment: This worked for me, but is this is the right way, I was thinking if there is any page/control event which I can leverage to set the initial value

Comment: sorry but this doesn't exist,dropdown sets by default the first item in the list to be the first selected item,so you have to override this default by any edit you want

Answer (score 2):

change label text on pageload. See below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!this.IsPostBack)
     {
          myDictionary.Add("1", "Test Address 1");
          myDictionary.Add("2", "Test Address 2");
          myDictionary.Add("3", "Test Address 3");
          myDictionary.Add("4", "Test Address 4");
          myDictionary.Add("5", "Test Address 5");

          drpTest.DataSource = myDictionary;
          drpTest.DataTextField = "Key";
          drpTest.DataValueField = "Value";
          drpTest.DataBind();

          drpTest.SelectedIndex = 2;
          lblAddress.Text = drpTest.SelectedItem.Value;     **// add this**
     }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: My question is why selected index does not fire if I set its value to 2

Comment: By changing value, you can't call selected index change method. You have to call it manually after changing selectedindex. Like drpTest_SelectedIndexChanged(drpTest,EventArgs.empty);

Answer (score 0):

When you define the dropdown include drpTest.AutoPostBack = true
This will trigger the SelectedIndexChanged event when changed.